# codeigniter_4 the redirection method is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

```
    public function isAuth($page,$data){
        $session = \Config\Services::session();
        if(empty($session->get(SES_ADMIN_USER_ID))){
            return redirect()->route('admin/login');
        }else{
            $this->load_page($page,$data);
        }
    }
```

when the sessionis not set the code is going in the if condition but  this redirection is not working

```
return redirect()->('admin/login');
```

this is muy route

```
$routes->get('/admin/login', 'Admin\Admin_Controller::load_login');
```

i tried other redirection methods but they are not working

Comment: `return redirect()->route('admin/login');` this should work

Comment: tried not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is: `return redirect()->to('admin/login');`

Comment: i triied it  return redirect()->to('admin/login'); but not working

Comment: Whats not working? Does it error?